# regular expression to get string/word between quotation marks in English

Tags: c, regex

I would like to get a string between quotation marks
I know a solution that's:

```
/'.*?'/
```

But the problem is that it doesn't work with the possessive case or contraction case in English
for example:

```
What is the name of Mario's brother in the 'Super Mario' video games?
```

or

```
He's my brother
```

it can't work with those sentences

Comment: What language are you using?  There is probably a solution that's already been written that we can point you to.

Comment: I use c but the language doesn't matter!

Comment: @JMBise sure it does. Regexes are a bit different in every implementation, and sometimes these differences matter a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to make sure that there is no word boundary before the opening and after the closing `'`:

```
/\B'.*?'\B/
```

The position between a word character (usually letters, digits, underscores in regular expressions) and a non-word character (anything else or an end of the string) constitutes a word boundary (`\b`). All other positions are matched by `\B`.

[Working demo.](http://regexr.com?32vhr)

[Further reading on word boundaries.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

By the way, if you want to allow double quotes, too, you can assure consistent delimiting with a backreference:

```
/\B(['"]).*?\1\B/
```

If you would just use `['"]` twice, then something like `here "my' string` would give you a match, which you probably don't want. Note that depending on how you define your regex, you might need to escape one of the quotes.

Comment: That's the same assumption Word makes for "smart quotes" and why it has been getting them wrong since the '90s.  The general problem of quoting cannot be handled by a regular expression.  The apostrophe is one of the most overloaded characters in the ASCII character set, and you need a tremendous amount of context to solve it in the general case.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy yup, thanks for pointing it out explicitly. Of course, entirely correct usage of quotes/apostrophes is part of natural language parsing, which is way beyond the scope of regular expressions. However this assumption should probably catch most of the simpler cases.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET Regex flavor you have balancing groups, and there might be Regex libraries for C that supports that as well. Here is a solution using balancing groups at least:

```
(?<NestingCount>\B'\b)(?:(?<NestingCount>\B'\b)|(?<-NestingCount>\b(?:[?])?'\B)|.)+?(?(NestingCount)(?!))
```

This works for both your examples (assuming they are surrounded with ').

A few comments about my solution:

- I use balancing groups to be able to identify nested quoted text (like 'Super Mario').
- I identify the start of any quote with `\B'\b`.
- I identify the end of any quote with `\b(?:[?])?'\B`. The `(?:[?])?` part is to allow a word to end with an optional ?-mark, and you can add more to the group (`[?]`) if I have forgot other word endings that should be present.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
/(?<!\w)[\'\"][\w\s\?\'\.\!\,\;\:]+[\'\"](?!\w)/
```

Comment: These lookarounds are in any possible case equivalent to the negative workboundary `\B`. But lookbehinds are not as widely supported (well and I find them a bit obscuring compared with `\B`).

Comment: Also this does not allow the use of apostrophes inside quoted strings (like `For example, in the game 'Yoshi's Island'.`)

Answer (score 0):

Go with simple pattern `/\B'.*?'\B/`